# Trifold Brochure: Where do the fold lines go-?

Tags: adobe-indesign

In a trifold brocure, there are two fold lines. What are the measurements for the fold lines in inches?

Comment: Won't the entirely depend on the size of the paper? It's either too broad to answer or unclear to me exactly what you want answered here.

Comment: agree with you @Johannes.  Also I think this is easy to google and get exactly what you're looking for

Comment: What type of tri fold? Enveloping or "accordion"? Different tri fold, different answers. Accordion = equal panels. Envelop = answers of binky and tman50. Note: tri fold = 3 folds, not 3 panels. But the concept is the same as explained below but with 4 panels instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for 8.5 x 11 (since you provided no dimensions), I just googled for trifold brochure templates and found several links.  Here is one for you:

http://www.expresspressprinting.com/id80.html

> If you are designing a brochure that will letterfold, meaning the 3rd panel will fold inside the 1st and 2nd panels, you must provide gripper space and allow for the fact that letter folding makes the last panel a different size. For example, for an 8.5x11 letterfold brochure, the 1st and 2nd panels will measure 3 11/16" and the 3rd panel will measure 3 5/8". To accomodate the different sizes, but still keep the content of each panel centered, you must size and position the layout area of the last panel differently. See Figs. 2 & 3.
>   Here is a basic layout for 8.5x11:

[image: inside brochure template]
[image: outside brochure template]

- left margin=3/8",
- 1st column=2 15/16",
- 1st gutter=3/4",
- 2nd column=2 15/16",
- 2nd gutter=3/4",
- 3rd column=2 7/8",
- right margin=3/8".

Answer (score 1):

regardless of size--the panel that tucks inside needs to be 1/16" narrower than the other two panels--margins and gutters don't matter as you may have an image that crosses over the folds--for an 8.5x11--two panels would be 3-11/16 and the third (that tucks in) would be 3-5/8